# Jquery toggle span text in trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm so close to figuring this out, i think. I'm new to javascript, but here's my situation.

I've got some lists hidden by default. Clicking on the headers displays the lists. I want the span in the header to change from '+' to '-' to hide and show respectively.

The problem i'm running into is the span changes for both headers, instead of just the one being clicked.

```
    <div>
    <h3 class = "trigger"><span>+</span>Heading 1</h3>
    <ul class = "toggle">
        <li>Line One</li>
        <li>Line Two</li>
        <li>Line Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <h3 class = "trigger"><span>+</span>Heading 2</h3>
    <ul class = "toggle">
        <li>Line One</li>
        <li>Line Two</li>
        <li>Line Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the accompanying javascript for it.

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".toggle").slideToggle(function(){
    $('span').text(
        $('.toggle').is(':visible') ? '-' : '+');
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toddj/sWvbq/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    var trigger = $(this);
    $(this).next(".toggle").slideToggle(function(){
    trigger.children('span').text(
        $('.toggle').is(':visible') ? '-' : '+');
    });
});
```

​

Answer (score 1):

You need to specifically tell javascript to only hide span related to that header

http://jsfiddle.net/sWvbq/5/

One way of doing that :)

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    var _that = $(this); // remember parent
    $(this).next(".toggle").slideToggle(function(){
    _that.find('span').text( // only toggle span related to parent
        $('.toggle').is(':visible') ? '-' : '+');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next(".toggle").slideToggle(function(){
        $this.find("span").text($(this).is(':visible') ? '-': '+');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N8YVD/

Comment: Hi Kevin, do you know why the following fails to work? http://pastebin.com/9gJABGv7 - many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you were pretty close :) Here is the update [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sWvbq/6/) (there are multiple approaches to reach it). If you access `$('span')` inside `slideToggle` you will acccess all spans thats why it changes both. You need to access only the span from clicked heading so you will have to traverse back to it.

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".toggle").slideToggle(function(){
    $(this).prev().children('span').text(
        $('.toggle').is(':visible') ? '-' : '+');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, it clears things up for me. I could understand why it was doing it, i just didn't know how to grab the child of the of the thing i was clicking.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery when you use the . operator you are asking jQuery to get all of the DOM elements with a CLASS of toggle.  If you want one to change, you can ask for a specific id.  Name them uniquely, and access with $('#IDHERE') and you will get one to update and the other will stay the same.